# Is there any way to avoid the 'saving changes is not permitted' error when trying to change the schema

Tags: ssms

I'm not a SQL server expert by any means, and I'm hoping this is something simple.  The scenario: I create a new database with all the defaults, then add a table with a primary key and two nvarchar(max) fields, but I forget to set the identity specification on the key so I go back and try to change it the IsIdentity property from No to Yes and I get the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [this](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/sql-server-prevent-saving-changes-that-require-table-to-be-re-created/) after posting my question - leaving up to moderators to decide if this is something to keep or not...

The simplest way to bypass this error is to go into Option – Designers and uncheck the option Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation.